# Яндекс API кластер

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Не получается разобраться с кластерами в яндекс карты api.
Информацию и уроки брал отсюда: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/
Вот, что получилось(код отображен ниже). Проблема в том, что объекты не отображаются на карте. Если есть возможность, то выложите рабочий пример, желательно простой. Примеры из Яндекс песочницы использовал, но они сложные и разобраться в них не получилось.

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
center: [55.354968,86.087314],
zoom: 12,
controls: ['zoomControl'],
}, {
searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
}),
myGeoObjects = [];
myGeoObjects[0] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [55.354968,86.087314] },
    properties: {
        clusterCaption: 'Геообъект №1',
        balloonContentBody: 'Содержимое балуна геообъекта №1.'
    }
});
myGeoObjects[1] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [55.354968,86.087314] },
    properties: {
        clusterCaption: 'Геообъект №2',
        balloonContentBody: 'Содержимое балуна геообъекта №2.'
    }
});

var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({ clusterDisableClickZoom: true });
clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);


;}
```

Comment: у вас просто ошибка - создаете вы карту в переменной myMap, а кластер пытаетесь добавить на карту map. Если это исправить, объекты отобразятся https://jsfiddle.net/jp1rmsr7/ Об ошибке вы могли узнать из консоли - ваш код выдает там Cannot read property 'add' of undefined как раз на строчке с неправильным названием переменной

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось.